# Accessings fields directly in Django adminform template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have a ton of fields that I need to layout (reorder) in a specific way  the form (with some other extra html stuff). I created *change_form.html* file for my model, which itself works.

The problem is all examples are looping over the fields, I just want to refer to each field by name.

```
# this works
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
  {% for line in fieldset %}
    {% for field in line %}
      <p>{{ field.field }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

*I know you can customise the admin.ModelAdmin with fieldsets, etc.. But that's not what I want.*

I was trying different ways like below, but it doesn't work:

```
# assuming the admin model has the fields: first_name & last_name
{% block content %}

  <!-- doesn't work !!! ->
  {{ adminform.fieldsets.0.1.fields.first_name.field }}
  {{ adminform.fieldsets.0.1.fields.last_name.field }}

  <!-- neither does this -->
  {{ adminform.fields.first_name.field }}
  {{ adminform.fields.last_name.field }}

{% endblock %}
```

Now this doesn't work, is there any efficient way to directly access the fields I need?

Answer (score 2):

You can call object with `{{ original }}`.
So if you have field: last_name you can call it in template like this `{{ original.last_name }}`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking in the complete wrong direction. Its actually super simple, you can use it as follows.

When you have model with a field `last_name` you can access the field:

```
# change_form.html (custom)
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block field_sets %}

    # get the label
    <label for="{{ adminform.form.last_name.label }}">
       {{ adminform.form.last_name.id_for_label }}
    </label>

    # get the html widget
    {{ adminform.form.last_name }}

    # get the field value
    {{ adminform.form.last_name.value }}

    # create your own input (without the label)
    <input name="{{ adminform.form.last_name.html_name }}">

    # some other fields you can reference
    {{ adminform.form.last_name.max_length }}
    {{ adminform.form.last_name.required }}
    {{ adminform.form.last_name.help_text }}
    {{ adminform.form.last_name.label_suffix }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can create a ModelForm to be used in your ModelAdmin, check de docs -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form

another way could be setting fields tuple, docs here -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields

Hope this drives U in the right path.